# Sub-classing an edit control (in full window, NOT dialogue)

Tags: c++, winapi, controls, subclassing

I've been trying to figure this out for ages and I'm absolutely stumped! I'm trying to subclass an edit control so I can capture when the enter key is pressed.

I've seen lots of other posts about sub-classing with snippets of code to add to do it, but I can't seem to implement it into my application. I apologize if I'm making a stupid mistake, but I simply cannot figure this out.

*I know this code is poorly written and has no error checking, but I wanted to post as little code as possible to convey the problem.*

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <wchar.h>

HWND editHWND;
WNDPROC wpOrigEditProc;

LRESULT APIENTRY EditSubclassProc(HWND hwnd,UINT uMsg,WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    if (uMsg == WM_CHAR)
    {
        //do my stuff
    }
    return CallWindowProc(wpOrigEditProc, hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}


LRESULT WINAPI MsgProc( HWND hWnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam )
{
    switch( msg )
    {
    case WM_CREATE:

        wpOrigEditProc = (WNDPROC) SetWindowLong(editHWND,GWL_WNDPROC, (LONG) EditSubclassProc);
        SetWindowLong(editHWND, GWL_WNDPROC,(LONG) wpOrigEditProc);
        break;

    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage( 0 );
        return 0;
    }

    return DefWindowProc( hWnd, msg, wParam, lParam );
}

int WINAPI wWinMain( HINSTANCE hInst,HINSTANCE,LPWSTR,INT )
{
    WNDCLASSEX wc = { sizeof( WNDCLASSEX ),CS_CLASSDC,MsgProc,0,0,
                      GetModuleHandle( NULL ),NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,
                      L"My Window",NULL };
    RegisterClassEx( &wc );

    HWND hWnd = CreateWindowW( L"My Window",L"test application",
                              WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,100,100,800,600,
                              NULL,NULL,wc.hInstance,NULL );

    editHWND = CreateWindow( L"edit",L"hi there",WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | WS_BORDER,100,100,300,50,hWnd,(HMENU)17,0,0);

    ShowWindow( hWnd,SW_SHOWDEFAULT );

    MSG msg;
    ZeroMemory( &msg,sizeof( msg ) );
    while( msg.message != WM_QUIT )
    {
        if( PeekMessage( &msg,NULL,0,0,PM_REMOVE ) )
        {
            TranslateMessage( &msg );
            DispatchMessage( &msg );
        }
    }

    UnregisterClass( L"My Window",wc.hInstance );
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Where is `editHWND` created? Does it actually exist when your window gets `WM_CREATE`?

Comment: Just below where the main window
    hWnd
is created. And I think so yeah.

Comment: `WM_CREATE` is called before the call to `CreateWindowEx` returns, so I think you will find that at the time you're trying to sub-class the window it hasn't actually been created yet.

Comment: You acknowledge that you don't do any error checking, but when trying to figure out why something isn't working, *checking for errors* often can give you a clue what's wrong.

Comment: @jamesdlin good point, I probably should have included error checking, but I didn't want the code to seem overly complex or too long.

JonathanPotter thank you VERY much, it works fine now, I did not realise that.

One more quick question, when the return key is pressed, I use WM_SETTEXT to clear the buffer, however windows still processes the return key and I get a bleep on the machine because it cannot create a new line (if it's set to ES_MULTILINE a new line is created.) How do I stop windows from processing the return key so the input stays blank?

Thanks

Comment: Did you set the `ES_WANTRETURN` style on the edit control?

Comment: If you don't want default processing for the [Enter] key don't pass the message on to the default window proc.

Comment: @Tim Thanks I managed to figure that out just now. Turns out I don't need to go through the whole Sub Classing shenanigans after all as that was all I wanted to do, was interesting to learn about though.

Answer (score 0):

`MsgProc()` is the window procedure for the "My Window" window.  When you are processing the `WM_CREATE` message, you are processing that window's creation, before the second `CreateWindow()` has been called to create the Edit window.

Worse, even if you were subclassing the Edit window correctly, you are removing the subclass immediately after setting it.  So `EditSubClassProc()` would never have a change to be called anyway.

Since you are not defining a custom window procedure for the Edit window at the time it is being created, you cannot use a `WM_CREATE` message to subclass the Edit window (unless you use a message hook, which is overkill in this situation).  Just call `SetWindowLong()` after `CreateWindow()` has exited.

Try this:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <wchar.h>

HWND editHWND = NULL;
WNDPROC wpOrigEditProc = NULL;

LRESULT APIENTRY EditSubclassProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    if (uMsg == WM_CHAR)
    {
        //do my stuff
    }
    return CallWindowProc(wpOrigEditProc, hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}

LRESULT WINAPI MsgProc( HWND hWnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam )
{
    switch( msg )
    {
    case WM_CLOSE:
        DestroyWindow(hWnd);
        return 0;

    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage( 0 );
        return 0;
    }

    return DefWindowProc( hWnd, msg, wParam, lParam );
}

int WINAPI wWinMain( HINSTANCE hInst,HINSTANCE,LPWSTR,INT )
{
    WNDCLASSEX wc = { sizeof( WNDCLASSEX ),CS_CLASSDC,MsgProc,0,0,
                      GetModuleHandle( NULL ),NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,
                      TEXT("My Window"),NULL };
    RegisterClassEx( &wc );

    HWND hWnd = CreateWindowW( TEXT("My Window"),TEXT("test application"),
                              WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,100,100,800,600,
                              NULL,NULL,wc.hInstance,NULL );

    editHWND = CreateWindow( TEXT("edit"),TEXT("hi there"),WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | WS_BORDER,100,100,300,50,hWnd,(HMENU)17,0,0);

    wpOrigEditProc = (WNDPROC) SetWindowLongPtr(editHWND, GWL_WNDPROC, (LONG_PTR) EditSubclassProc);

    ShowWindow( hWnd, SW_SHOWDEFAULT );

    MSG msg;
    while ( GetMessage( &msg,NULL,0,0 ) > 0 )
    {
        TranslateMessage( &msg );
        DispatchMessage( &msg );
    }

    UnregisterClass( TEXT("My Window"),wc.hInstance );
    return 0;
}
```

With that said, another way to subclass a window is to use `SetWindowSubclass()` instead:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <wchar.h>

HWND editHWND = NULL;

LRESULT CALLBACK EditSubclassProc(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam, UINT_PTR uIdSubclass, DWORD_PTR dwRefData)
{
    if (uMsg == WM_CHAR)
    {
        //do my stuff
    }

    return DefSubclassProc(hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}

LRESULT WINAPI MsgProc( HWND hWnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam )
{
    switch( msg )
    {
    case WM_CLOSE:
        DestroyWindow(hWnd);
        return 0;

    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage( 0 );
        return 0;
    }

    return DefWindowProc( hWnd, msg, wParam, lParam );
}

int WINAPI wWinMain( HINSTANCE hInst,HINSTANCE,LPWSTR,INT )
{
    WNDCLASSEX wc = { sizeof( WNDCLASSEX ),CS_CLASSDC,MsgProc,0,0,
                      GetModuleHandle( NULL ),NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,
                      TEXT("My Window"),NULL };
    RegisterClassEx( &wc );

    HWND hWnd = CreateWindowW( TEXT("My Window"),TEXT("test application"),
                              WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,100,100,800,600,
                              NULL,NULL,wc.hInstance,NULL );

    editHWND = CreateWindow( TEXT("edit"),TEXT("hi there"),WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | WS_BORDER,100,100,300,50,hWnd,(HMENU)17,0,0);

    SetWindowSubclass(editWND, EditSubclassProc, 0, 0);

    ShowWindow( hWnd, SW_SHOWDEFAULT );

    MSG msg;
    while ( GetMessage( &msg,NULL,0,0 ) > 0 )
    {
        TranslateMessage( &msg );
        DispatchMessage( &msg );
    }

    UnregisterClass( TEXT("My Window"),wc.hInstance );
    return 0;
}
```